# Query specific field based on max sequence number

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a record set where some of the rows are duplicated. In particular, they are duplicated for the last three rows of the record set. Of the entire four rows, the correct result set that I desire would include the first row and the last row. I desire this because for a particular SARAPPD_TERM_CODE_ENTRY, the record needed is the one where the SARAPPD_SEQ_NO value is at its max. So, the first row because for that particular term, the sequence number is maxed at one and the last row because the sequence number is maxed at six. Image and query are below.

[image]

```
select ppd.sarappd_seq_no, ppd.sarappd_term_code_entry, ppd.sarappd_apdc_code, 
   dap. dap.saradap_term_code_entry, 
   spri.spriden_id, 
   t.sgbstdn_astd_code, t.* 
from sgbstdn t 
left join spriden spri on t.sgbstdn_pidm = spri.spriden_pidm
left join saradap dap on spri.spriden_pidm = dap.saradap_pidm
join sarappd ppd on dap.saradap_pidm = ppd.sarappd_pidm
where t.sgbstdn_astd_code not in ('AS', 'DS', 'WD', 'SU', 'LA') 
and t.sgbstdn_stst_code = 'AS'
and spri.spriden_change_ind is null
and spri.spriden_id = '123456789'
and (ppd.sarappd_apdc_code = 25 or ppd.sarappd_apdc_code = 30
or   ppd.sarappd_apdc_code =35)
and ppd.sarappd_term_code_entry = dap.saradap_term_code_entry

                      --where b.sarappd_term_code_entry = ppd.sarappd_term_code_entry)
order by ppd.sarappd_term_code_entry
```

I believe this is a simple "where this = ( select max() ) type of query but I've been trying some different things and nothing is working. I'm not getting the results I want. So with that said, any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make your query simpler?  For example, can you get rid of the extra tables and just do a self query and use SELECT XXX FROM YourTable WHERE APDC_CODE = (SELECT MAX(APDC_CODE) FROM ...)  UNION ALL SELECT XXX FROM YourTable WHERE APDC_CODE = (SELECT MIN(APDC_CODE) FROM ...) in order to simplify your code into something that works.  Then add the other tables back in one at a time.

Comment: What rdbms is this? SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: @Missy I will attempt to do this more to see if I may have missed something. I had been plugging in table by table before...and also "re-arranging" the tables in efforts to go about the issue in another way. But I'll see what else I can come up with

Comment: @SQLChao Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH cte 
AS
(select 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SARAPPD_TERM_CODE_ENTRY ORDER BY SARAPPD_SEQ_NO DESC) AS RN
   ppd.sarappd_seq_no, 
   ppd.sarappd_term_code_entry, 
   ppd.sarappd_apdc_code, 
   dap. dap.saradap_term_code_entry, 
   spri.spriden_id, 
   t.sgbstdn_astd_code, t.* 
from sgbstdn t 
left join spriden spri on t.sgbstdn_pidm = spri.spriden_pidm
left join saradap dap on spri.spriden_pidm = dap.saradap_pidm
join sarappd ppd on dap.saradap_pidm = ppd.sarappd_pidm
where t.sgbstdn_astd_code not in ('AS', 'DS', 'WD', 'SU', 'LA') 
and t.sgbstdn_stst_code = 'AS'
and spri.spriden_change_ind is null
and spri.spriden_id = '123456789'
and (ppd.sarappd_apdc_code = 25 or ppd.sarappd_apdc_code = 30
or   ppd.sarappd_apdc_code =35)
and ppd.sarappd_term_code_entry = dap.saradap_term_code_entry
order by ppd.sarappd_term_code_entry) a


SELECT *
FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
```